# @route annotation overriding another route

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a staticController with actions for the following example links:

/register
/imprint

this is the example annotation:

```
/**
*@Route("/imprint", name="user.static.imprint") 
*/
```

And now i have the following annotation for linking other pages with dynamic linknames:

```
/**
 *@Route("/{area}", requirements={"id" = "!imprint"}, name="user.area.index") 
 */
```

I'm using the path() function in twig to create the links.

The generated link /imprint 
ist now routing to the second annotation.
How can i avoid this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try to put imprint action method above index

Comment: they are different controllers.

Comment: then include imprint controller route config before index...

Comment: what do you mean with before index?

Comment: but i answered, that they are different controllers. Thats why i can't put imprint action method above index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second route matches same pattern as first and interferes with it, so you need to put first in priority.

Somewhere in your project you're importing these two controllers routes as annotations (Probably `/app/config/routing.yml`). Looks something like this:

```
bar_route:
    resource: "@FooBundle/Controller/BarController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Right now most likely second controller import is above first. Reverse that.

Comment: Hello, i imported the whole controller folder as an annotation.AcmeDemoBundle:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

Comment: Well just break it down manually like in my example and make sure controller with second route is listed first.

Comment: when i put this into the routing.yml i have the following error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093322/symfony2-routing-failed-cannot-redeclare-class