# symfony2 routing failed - cannot redeclare class

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to change my routing from annotations to thr routing.yml.
This is now the only configuration in my routing_dev.yml:

```
user.index:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:User/UserIndex:index }
```

And this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Acme\MyBundle\Controller\User\UserIndexController in C:\Users\gp\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\project\src\Acme\MyBundle\Controller\User\UserIndexController.php on line 56
```

Why does it happen? This is really the only class with this name. I have no annotations in the UserIndexController.

Has anybody an idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sure you think it's the only class with this name but PHP fails with this error for a reason :) And no, it's not route related. Also your _controller config looks weird "IdiotsP1Bundle:User/UserIndex:index" - does this really work? with the slash inbetween?

Comment: The userindexController is in the folder Controller/User/UseriIndexcontroller.php  When i deete User/ then the routing doesn't find the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to grep/find in your project for `Acme\MyBundle\Controller\User\UserIndexController`.

You maybe **really** have the class declared twice.

Then, try to replace

```
`AcmeMyBundle:User/UserIndex:index`
```

with
    `AcmeMyBundle:User\\UserIndex:index`

Depending of the version of symfony, it will search for a "namespace like" and/or a "path like".

Comment: it wasn't the problem, but thanks. i don't removed my annotations for testing the index and i rendered UserIndex:area with the twig render function. I think one of those thinks was the problem but now the render function works too. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This happened to mee too, it was my controller file, **I had the namespace wrong**.